# What happens to wonders in a city when it is razed?

Tags: civilization-5

What happens to a wonder in a city, if i raze the city?

Does the wonder disappear with its bonus'?

or do the wonders switch to another city as if it was that city who had build it?

Answer (score 12):

They certainly don't switch to other cities.  From the manual:

> ### Razing the City
>
> If you raze the city, it’s gone. For good. All of its buildings, wonders, and citizens are no more.

Comment: When there is a city with a wonder in it. I tend to raze it if I find the wonder does not offer benefits to my current or future situation. Such as, extra defence when enemy troops are in my land which is usually not the case by then.